# Windows 10 after 1809 update users have "Allow remote assistance connections to this computer" grayed out

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-assistance

So I ran 1809 update to couple of PC's with WSUS.
After the update we couldn't connect with remote assistance (We have an ongoing issue with one software that needs Admin password after such upgrades).

1. ```
   gpupdate /force
   ```

   GPO has Enabled "Configure Offer Remote Assistance"
2. ```
   reg add "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Remote Assistance" /v fAllowToGetHelp /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
   ```

   it is set to 1. Still unchecked and grayed out.
3. ```
   netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="remote assistance" new enable=Yes
   ```

   Did not help
4. Tried restarting.
5. ```
   reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services" /v fAllowToGetHelp /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
   ```

   adds the check in the *allow remote assistance* checkbox, but still doesn't work

Any idea what could have been changed?

Discovered that you still can Remote Assist if you run Remote Assistance as Domain Admin.